# .preventDefault() method not working with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent the default behavior of clicking on an anchor element like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default start-match" data-call="start" href="/matches/256/start.json" data-method="patch" data-model="Match" rel="nofollow">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span> Iniziata
</a>
```

with a javascript like this:

```
  $(document).on(
          'click',
          "a",
          function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
  );
```

but this code is not preventing the default behavior, and the link is followed. why?

my jquery version is 1.10 and I'm using turbolinks

Comment: did you wrap it within $(document).ready(function(){...});

Comment: [The code works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/7VYuN/1/) `$(document).ready(...)` is useless here. Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: That works just fine, the only reason it wouldn't work is if jQuery wasn't loaded (the document is always available).

Comment: And why would you stop propagation at the `document` level?

Comment: @minitech - to make sure it doesn't reach the window ;-) ....

Comment: If you're using some other package (and something called "turbolinks" sounds suspicious), make sure that your code appears **before** the other code in the document. If another event handler is triggered before yours, then yours can't prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

As per i know in anchor tag first preference given to HREF then onclick event. so by default HREF url get call first.

If you dont want to call anchor url then you can replace HREF tag with

`<a href="javascript:;">....</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like event.preventDefault() works only from jQuery 1.7

The same JavaScript code with different results:
$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("a").on('click',

    function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //event.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/visvam07/1201gf1d/) fiddle with jQuery 1.6.4 and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/visvam07/1201gf1d/1/) with jQuery 1.7.2

Answer (score -4):

I think what this is trying to do is call 'preventDefault' on document, when in reality, you want the 'a' event to be prevented. This is more likely to work:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e..stopPropagation();
    // rest of your stuff
});
```

if this works as expected, 'stopPropagation' might not even be necessary

Comment: It’s all the same event.

Comment: This is completely different, it's no longer delegated, and preventDefault works fine in delegated handlers, so that's not the issue.